# Sesión activa de usuarios en Auth0

Tags: vue.js, login, autenticación, auth0

Estoy usuando el SDK de Auth0 para vue js...pero cuando accedo a su método para verificar si la sesión del usuario esta activa para impedir que haya otra sesión activa en el futuro, me da un undefined:

así accedo a la sesión en Auth0:

```
const response = await this.$auth0.checkSession();
//response: undefined
```

y esta es la configuración de auth o en mi app

```
createApp(App)
    .use(
        createAuth0({
            domain: configAuth.domain,
            client_id: configAuth.clientId,
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
            useRefreshTokens: configAuth.useRefreshTokens,
            audience: configAuth.audience,
            serverUrl: configAuth.serverUrl
        })
    )
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(Donut)
    .use(i18n)
    .component('LanguageSwitch', LanguageSwitch)
    .mount('#app')
```

me hace falta algo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que `checkSession()` genera otro token y según la documentación no regresa nada, tendrías que usar `isAuthenticated()` que regresa un booleano, o bien podrías implementar algo llamado `Silent Authentication`

Documentación:

[Using checkSession to acquire new tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js#using-checksession-to-acquire-new-tokens)

[Configure Silent Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/configure-silent-authentication#successful-authentication-responses)